# Close view controller

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

In my OS X app I've 2 views: one for login and one just present the content of a file. I've create 2 .xib file one for the login form and one with a table view. The logic of the app works nice, but I'm having issue by presentation the view controller. 
When user click on login button, the view controller with login form should be dismissed and the view controller with table view should be presented.
When user click on logout button, the view controller with table view should be dismissed and the view controller with login form should be presented.
For now to switch between the 2 view controllers I'm using the following code:

```
HistoryViewController *historyViewController = [[HistoryViewController alloc]init];
[self presentViewControllerAsModalWindow:historyViewController];
```

but if the user click on the logout button it shows me the login view controller and if user press on the close button (the red button in top left corner) it shows me again the view controller without user is logged in. So how I can dismiss the table view controller after the user press on logout button? There's a way to hide/close the view controller?
I hope you can help me to fix this issue. Thank you

Comment: `- dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`?

Comment: I'm unable to find this method...

Comment: [dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I read your question I assume you present your logon screen as a separate panel in your application. There is little information to go on, but I would see three options for yopur application.

1. Present the logon screen as a view in the primary window. Whenn logon is successful, you swap the view in the main window from the logon screen to your table view. Swapping views in and out of a window is presented in another question on this site. [Xcode single window, display custom view from xib file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27975635/xcode-single-window-display-custom-view-from-xib-file/28001703#28001703)
2. Present, like you do now, the logon screen in a panel on top of your main window. I assume that you keep track whether the logon was successful or not. Use this status when making decisions on closing the panel. When someone closes the panel by pressing the close butten (red button on the top left), the window will send a "windowWillClose" notification to its file owner, usually the view controller. Implement this method an prohibit the window from closing when logon was unsuccessful. This way the user only has the option to successfully logon, or cancel the logon (you have to implement a method and button). Closing the window won't be possible. Inadvertently closing the panel with the red close button is not possible.
3. Empty the data source of your table view so that it will present an empty table. Start your application with a logon screen running on top of the table view. Only when the user successfully logged on, you fill your datasource and invoke "reloadData" to present the content of your table view. If the logon was unsuccessful or the user closes the panel, he will not be able to manipulatie the table view.

I would either go for the two views in a single window (option 1) or for the empty table view (option 3). Option 3 would be my preferred option. I hope this helps.